# Where "not a subtype of" in a function signature in Julia

Tags: polymorphism, julia

I want to have a function that takes anything except some specific type. Roughly speaking something like

```
function f(y::X) where y<:setdiff(Any,Real)
    return y
end
```

Is there a "not a subtype of" operator which acts like the opposite of `<:`? Any other way to achieve this?

Edit: This is wrong and not necessary to understand question or answers and so strikedthrough: <strike>The reason being that I want to have a specific method of the function `f` for any real and a general one for any arbitrary object. The problem is that if I just leave this function signature as `where y` then it will specialise the general function as a type Float64 which is more specific than the function I have written for any reals (`where y<:Real`).</strike>

Comment: Specialization is completely orthogonal to the type signature of a function. The latter merely acts as a filter. It doesn't effect specialization.

Comment: The function signature determines what specialisations of X are allowed. For instance X<:Real means only Real specialisations of Any are allowed to be compiled and used. I am asking whether we can write a function signature for the opposite (anything is allowed except Reals) which seems like a valid question.

Comment: The question is confusing. Why not have one method `f(x) = general_algo(x)` and one method `f(x::Real) = specific_algo(x)`? Then `Float64` will dispatch to the `specific_algo`. I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that the general function takes in any X (where X). The specific one takes in any real (where X<:Real). I am getting the problem that for reals (like Float64) it will specialise the more general function rather than the function that is specific to reals. I really need to cut Reals out of the general function in order to stop it from doing that

Comment: No it won't. It will dispatch to the specific method and specialize that. Everything that's _not_ a real will go to `general_algo`, and everything that _is_ a real (including `Float64`) will go to `specific_algo`.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry I made a mistake in tracing my bug. The question is basically redundant then.

Comment: It is however still a valid and answerable questions.You could even self answer with your current solution of declare both general and specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a "not a subtype of" operator (it's `>:`), but you do not need that operator to solve your problem.

If you just want a generic method for all types, and a specific for subtypes of Real, then you should do:

```
f(x::Any) = 1
f(x::Real) = 2
```

The first method is identical to just adding any type signature (i.e. `f(x) = 1`), and that function will work as a fallback for all argument types. However, since `Real` is more specific than `Any`, the second method will be used instead of the first if the input is a `Real`:

```
julia> f("Hello, world!"), f(0x01), f(1 + 2im), f(true)
(1, 2, 1, 2)
```

Note that you get maximal performance regardless - no matter what type signature you put in a method defintion, when the method is actually running, it will be compiled to a specific version depending on the *concrete* input types.

Comment: But "not a subtype" isn't equivalent to "a supertype" in general! Unrelated types can be incomparable.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually implement a "not a subtype" operator youself, by using dispatch:

```
notasubtype(::Type{T1}, ::Type{T2}) where {T2, T1 <: T2} = false
notasubtype(::Type, ::Type) = true

julia> notasubtype(Int, Bool)
true

julia> notasubtype(Bool, Integer)
false

julia> notasubtype(Bool, Real)
false

julia> notasubtype(Bool, Array)
true
```

But this will only allow you to determine the relation at runtime, not as a type constraint.  On the other hand, since we have shown this is possible, we can reuse the same principle in a concrete function:

```
f(x::T) where {T<:Real} = ... # T a subtype of Real 
f(x::T) where {T} = ...       # T not a subtype of Real
```

which you can write in simpler, equivalent terms as Jacob did:

```
f(x::Any) = ...
f(x::Real) = ...
```

(The order doesn't matter.)